# Include a class in another class

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, class, import

I have a main.js file and 2 classes files (.js of course). I'll use nodejs.

Here is what i need to achieve:

```
main.js                      class 1.js                 class 2.js
--------                     ---------                  ---------
callin class 1               doing somethin             do somethin
to do some work              but needing                and return results
                             the class 2
```

i used  `module.exports = ClassOne` in class 1 and  `const ClassOne = require('./Class 1.js');`, but now i have to import a class into classone, how?

i already used other questions to get to this point. I saw a rather confusing situation, but managed to came this far. now i dont really know how js works to understand how should i import successfully into a class thats being included itself.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: then just do the same, tzn `module.exports = ClassTwo` in class two, and `require('./class 2.js');` in class one

Answer (score 1):

class2.js

```
class Class2 {
  constructor(){}
  doSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(`I did something too!`);
    });
  }
}

exports.Class2 = Class2;
```

class1.js

```
const Class2 = require('./class2').Class2;

class Class1 {
  constructor(){}
  async doSomething() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const class2 = new Class2();
      const msg = await class2.doSomething();
      resolve(`Look! I did something! => ${msg}`);
    });
  }
}

exports.Class1 = Class1;
```

main.js

```
const Class1 = require('./class1').Class1;

const class1 = new Class1();
class1.doSomething().then(msg => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Run the project with node

```
node main.js
```

Output will be:

```
Look! I did something! => I did something too!
```

Comment: i'll try right now. are you saying that when i require a class it keeps the things outside the class definition too?

Comment: When you `require` a file, you create an instance of all the objects that have been exported from the imported file. Anything not being exported is ignored by the file `require`-ing. If you have code that is not encapsulated in a function, it will run immediately upon using `require` for the file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the other 2 JS classes with module.exports, and whichever file needs (main.js I believe) needs to import them using require and proper file path.

```
//class1.js
function class1() {
    return 'I am class1';
}

module.exports = class1;


//class2.js
function class2() {
    return 'I am class1';
}

module.exports = class2;


//Main.js
const class1 = require('./class1.js');
const class2 = require('./class2.js');


console.log(class1());
console.log(class2());
```

Comment: this may be wrong, because i need class2 only in class1

Comment: Its just a demonstration of how to import and export files, you can call any file from any other file, totally on your use case, ✌️